# How to find objects where elems of included array have a field? In mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongoose

There is a schema of homeworks:

```js
const schema = new Schema({
  dateAssign: { type: Date, default: Date.now, index: true },
  teacher: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'user', index: true },
  lesson: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'lesson', index: true },
  exercises: [
    { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'exercise' },
  ],
});
mongoose.model('homework', schema)
```

An exercise's schema:

```js
const schema = new Schema({
  block: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'lessonblock', index: true },
  variant: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'variant', index: true },
  result: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'exerciseresult', index: true },
  variables: { type: Schema.Types.Mixed, default: {} },
  start_at: { type: Date },
  lock: { type: Boolean, default: false, index: true },
});
mongoose.model('exercise', schema);
```

How to find all homeworks where in exercises all elements has a field 'lock' = true?
I have tried, but it didn't work:

```js
const HWs = await Homework.find({ teacher, 'exercises.lock': true }, null, { sort: { dateAssign: -1 }, limit: 20 })
```

Comment: `{ teacher, 'exercises.lock': true }` why you have `teacher` here?

Comment: it's an object upper in my code.